# php pdo, filtering result not working with NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've two mysql tables:
One which holds a date / time / description.
Second one holds also the time the user can select. Just a simple list with 8:30,9:00 and so on.

Now i want wants to check by date when a time is beable it shows just the table Time, but with  except the time which was in agenda already used.

My code so far:

```
 public function checkTime($date){  
        // loop trough agenda, by date which i get from the function parameter
        $fetch = $this->dbprocess()->prepare("SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE datum = :date");
        $fetch->bindParam(':date', $date);
        $fetch->execute(); // execute this one
        // this is the query which gets the whole time data, get here data from $fetch and then display ONLY the data which isn't in use yet by agenda
        $result = $this->dbprocess()->prepare("SELECT * FROM uren WHERE NOT uur IN (?)");


        $result->execute(array("8:30,12:00")); // testing, this should be the data of agenda, so it gets the time which is in use by date from the first query

// display the time, with the time in agenda filtered(In this case only 8:30 , 12:00 should be filtered).
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $row['uur'];
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't display anything..
It runs something stuck in NOT and IN , but idk how...
It works if i do it as bindparams, and use Where .... AND .... , But this should work aswell...

I hope you understand my question, im really stuck.

Comment: Have you considered joining your tables?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15991146

Comment: Whatever i try it doesn't display anything or it doesn't filter...

Comment: I've it working now, thnx @Your common Sens, i messed up arrays with strings etc. If i found this question earlier i had solve it. Thnx! How its solved: Using a predefined array and put this in the execute, instead of DIRECTLY put it in an array in the execute, as i've it now.

Comment: @iLuvCode put your answer in an actual answer please, instead of a comment. :-) That way you'll get points for it.